# Share Pidgin logs via DropBox?

Tags: dropbox, logging, pidgin

Is it possible to share Pidgin logs via something like DropBox?  I do a lot of work with multiple machines (home office, work office, etc.), and would like the logs to be searchable from wherever I happen to be--that way, it's transparent to Pidgin where the logfile changes come from.

Comment: if you do struggle with this, maybe finch could work for you? I do that from a VPS out on the net, which accidentally avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary for you to separate the Chatlogs and the whole settings/profile folder? Because there is a good article an howtogeek about syncing the profile folder http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15053/sync-your-pidgin-profile-across-multiple-pcs-with-dropbox/

I don't do it with dropbox; but have the profile file on a truecrypt volume to sync it with both OSes on my dual-boot machine. It has some quirks with the plugins but it works.

And [apparently that doesn't help with Adium.](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/8467)

Comment: [When shouldn't I comment?](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment):
"Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!")" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that you end up being logged into more than one machine at once and the different instances of Pidgin fight to lock the log files. I suggest you make do with having a separate logfile for each instance of Pidgin and simply have the Pidgin folders sync independantly for you to refer to when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) on the folder where the logs are stored on both machines. It basically redirects the folder where the putty logs are stored to the folder you make in your dropbox. I am assuming you are on windows, but the same can be accomplished in Linux or OS X as well.

[Lifehacker did a nice write up on this](http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder) that explains it more thoroughly.